# Performance Optimization for Matrix Rotation

Tags: c, performance, optimization

I'm now trapped by a performance optimization lab in the book "Computer System from a Programmer's Perspective" described as following:

In a N*N matrix M, where N is multiple of 32, the rotate operation can be represented as:
     Transpose: interchange elements M(i,j) and M(j,i)
     Exchange rows: Row i is exchanged with row N-1-i

A example for matrix rotation(N is 3 instead of 32 for simplicity):

```
-------                          -------
|1|2|3|                          |3|6|9|
-------                          -------
|4|5|6|    after rotate is       |2|5|8|
-------                          -------
|7|8|9|                          |1|4|7|
-------                          -------
```

A naive implementation is:

```
#define RIDX(i,j,n) ((i)*(n)+(j))

    void naive_rotate(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
    {
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
         dst[RIDX(dim-1-j, i, dim)] = src[RIDX(i, j, dim)];
    }
```

I come up with an idea by inner-loop-unroll. The result is:

```
Code Version          Speed Up
  original                1x
 unrolled by 2           1.33x
 unrolled by 4           1.33x
 unrolled by 8           1.55x
 unrolled by 16          1.67x
 unrolled by 32          1.61x
```

I also get a code snippet from pastebin.com that seems can solve this problem:

```
void rotate(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
{
    int stride = 32;
    int count = dim >> 5;
    src += dim - 1; 
    int a1 = count;
    do {
        int a2 = dim;
        do {
            int a3 = stride;
            do {
                *dst++ = *src;
                src += dim;
            } while(--a3);
            src -= dim * stride + 1;
            dst += dim - stride;
        } while(--a2);
        src += dim * (stride + 1);
        dst -= dim * dim - stride;
    } while(--a1);
}
```

After carefully read the code, I think main idea of this solution is treat 32 rows as a data zone, and perform the rotating operation respectively. Speed up of this version is 1.85x, overwhelming all the loop-unroll version.

Here are the questions:

1. In the inner-loop-unroll version, why does increment slow down if the unrolling factor increase, especially change the unrolling factor from 8 to 16, which does not effect the same when switch from 4 to 8? Does the result have some relationship with depth of the CPU pipeline? If the answer is yes, could the degrade of increment reflect pipeline length?
2. What is the probable reason for the optimization of data-zone version? It seems that there is no too much essential difference from the original naive version.

EDIT:

My test environment is Intel Centrino Duo architecture and the verion of gcc is 4.4

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Kind regards!

Comment: Realistically it also helps to think about why you are doing this. Math optimizations start at simplifying the math expressions. Why is this operation needed?

Comment: You're right. But this problem, I think, has more relation with the system architecture than math simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of processor are you testing this on?  I dimly remember that unrolling loops helps when the processor can handle multiple operations at once, but only up to the maximum number of parallel executions.  So if your processor can only handle 8 simultaneous instructions, then unrolling to 16 won't help.  But someone with knowledge of more recent processor design will have to pipe up/correct me.

**EDIT**:  According to [this PDF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.intel.com%2Fassets%2Fpdf%2Fperfbrief%2Fmobiletechnology.pdf&ei=PrsHTMH2GZesNcCQ5bUE&usg=AFQjCNEcy0M5i-USBuaiw652kSB-3m8qgQ), the centrino core2 duo has two processors, each of which is capable of 4 simultaneous instructions.  It's generally not so simple, though.  Unless your compiler is optimizing across both cores (ie, when you run the task manager (if you're on windows, top if you're on linux), you'll see that CPU usage is maxed out), your process will be running on one core at a time.  The processor also features 14 stages of execution, so if you can keep the pipeline full, you'll get a faster execution.

Continuing along the theoretical route, then, you get a speed improvement of 33% with a single unroll because you're starting to take advantage of simultaneous instruction execution.  Going to 4 unrolls doesn't really help, because you're now still within that 4-simultaneous-instruction limit.  Going to 8 unrolls helps because the processor can now fill the pipeline more completely, so more instructions will get executed per clock cycle.

For this last, think about how a McDonald's drive through works (I think that that's relatively widespread?).  A car enters the drivethrough, orders at one window, pays at a second window, and receives food at a third window.  If a second drive enters when the first is still ordering, then by the time both finish (assuming each operation in the drive through takes one 'cycle' or time unit), then 2 full operations will be done by the time 4 cycles have elapsed.  If each car did all of their operations at one window, then the first car would take 3 cycles for ordering, paying, and getting food, and then the second car would also take 3 cycles for ordering, paying and getting food, for a total of 6 cycles.  So, operation time due to pipelining decreases.

Of course, you have to keep the pipeline full to get the largest speed improvement. 14 stages is a lot of stages, so going to 16 unrolls will give you some improvement still because more operations can be in the pipeline.

Going to 32 causing a decrease in performance may have to do with bandwidth to the processor from the cache (again a guess, can't know for sure without seeing your code exactly, as well as the machine code).  If all the instructions can't fit into cache or into the registers, then there is some time necessary to prepare them all to run (ie, people have to get into their cars and get to the drive through in the first place).  There will be some reduction in speed if they all get there all at once, and some shuffling of the line has to be done to make the operation proceed.

Note that each movement from src to dst is not free or a single operation.  You have the lookups into the arrays, and that costs time.

As for why the second version works so quickly, I'm going to hazard a guess that it has to do with the [] operator.  Every time that gets called, you're doing some lookups into both the src and dst arrays, resolving pointers to locations, and then retrieving the memory.  The other code is going straight to the pointers of the arrays and accessing them directly; basically, for each of the movements from src to dst, there are less operations involved in the move, because the lookups have been handled explicitly through pointer placement.  If you use [], these steps are followed:

- do any math inside the []
- take a pointer to that location (startOfArray + [] in memory)
- return the result of that location in memory

If you walk along with a pointer, you just do the math to do the walk (typically just an addition, no multiplication) and then return the result, because you've already done the second step.

If I'm right, then you might get better results with the second code by unrolling its inner loop as well, so that multiple operations can be pipelined simultaneously.

Comment: Just a comment on your first paragraph: Loop unrolling generally isn't so much about instruction parallelism as it is about keeping the CPU's instruction fetch pipeline full.

Comment: @Michael Burr: I'm going off of the thoughts in this: http://cs.oberlin.edu/~jdonalds/317/lecture18.html
and also with the intel compiler, where there are directives that parallelize the independent operations inside a loop. I'm not sure if gcc does that though, or if it's as you say, with keeping the CPU pipeline full.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the question I'm not sure about. My initial thought was some sort of cache problem, but you're only accessing each item once.

The other code could be faster for a coupe reasons.

1) The loops count down instead of up. Comparing a loop counter to zero costs nothing on most architectures (a flag is set by the decrement automatically) you have to explicitly compare to a max value with each iteration.

2) There is no math in the inner loop. You are doing a bunch of math in your inner loop. I see 2 subtractions in the main code and a multiply in the macro (which is used twice). There is also the implicit addition of the resulting indexes to the base address of the array which is avoided by the use of pointers (good addressing modes on x86 should eliminate this penalty too).

When writing optimized code, you always construct it bottom up from the inside. This means taking the inner-most loop and reducing its content to nearly zero. In this case, moving data is unavoidable. Incrementing a pointer is the bare minimum to get to the next item, the other pointer needs to add an offset to get to its next item. So at a minimum we have 4 operations: load, store, increment, add. If an architecture supported "move with post-increment" this would be 2 instructions total. On Intel I suspect it's 3 or 4 instructions. Anything more than this like subtractions and multiplication is going to add significant code.

Looking at the assembly code of each version should offer much insight.

If you run this repeatedly on a small matrix (32x32) that fits completely in cache you should should see even more dramatic differences in implementations. Running on a 1024x1024 matrix will be much slower than doing 1024 rotations of a single 32x32 even though the number of data copies is the same.

Answer (score 2):

1. The main purpose of loop unrolling is to reduce the time spent on the loop control (test for completion, incrementing counters, etc...).  This is a case of diminishing returns though, since as the loop is unrolled more and more, the time spent on loop control becomes less and less significant.  Like mmr said, loop unrolling may also help the compiler to execute things in parallel, but only up to a point.
2. The "data-zone" algorithm appears to be a version of a cache efficient matrix transpose algorithm.  The problem with computing a transpose the naive way is that it results in a lot of cache misses.  For the source array, you are accessing the memory along each row, so it is accessed in a linear manner, element-by-element.  However, this requires that you access the destination array along the columns, meaning you are jumping `dim` elements each time you access an element.  Basically, for each row of the input, you are traversing the memory of the entire destination matrix.  Since the whole matrix probably won't fit in the cache, memory has to be loaded and unloaded from the cache very often.

   The "data-zone" algorithm takes the matrix that you are accessing by column and only performs the transpose for 32 rows at a time, so the amount of memory you are traversing is `32xstride`, which should hopefully fit completely into the cache.  Basically the aim is to work on sub-sections that fit in the cache and reduce the amount of jumping around in memory.